# formtastic - how to prepopulate a string input with a value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I'm building an app, where users can give comments by just leaving their email to the comment.

I want them to be able to register directly from there, by a link with their email adress as a param 
(like: `<%= link_to register_path(:email => @comment.email %>` ) - so there is no existing user record yet.
this should be done by applying a value to the `form.input` field via the `:value` option.

But the following code doesn't work!

```
<%- if params[:email] -%>
  <%= f.input :email, :required => true, :value => params[:email] %>
<%- else -%>
  <%= f.input :email, :required => true %> 
<%- end -%>
```

I had a look inside the [formtastic rdoc](http://rdoc.info/projects/justinfrench/formtastic) and inside my local gem but couldn't find any option for that.

Suggestions anyone?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Yup, you got the right answer all by yourself!  Formtastic's rdoc is a mess, but we're working on it.  Another option if you want this purely at a view level is to use the `:input_html` option, which gives you direct access to HTML attributes of the input tag:

```
f.input :email, :input_html => { :value => params[:email] }
```

Comment: +1 as this is better than the accepted answer. If you want to do something like apply a view helper method to the input value, that code belongs in the view, not the controller.

Comment: This did the job, but shouldn't we have something like :value_method. I.E. f.input :my_date, :value_method => :formatted

Comment: Abe, feel free to add an issue on GH.

Answer (score 10):

sometimes the easiest things come to your mind by asking for them:

approach: do the job in the controller not the view!

```
if params[:email]
  @user = User.new(:email => params[:email])
else
  @user = User.new
end
```

sorry for bothering you!

Comment: Or simply: `@user = User.new(:email => params[:email])` if it's nil, the end result is the same. Except if @user initialization sets email.