# Phony Rails Normalize Number in View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, telephony

I'm trying to display a normalized phone number in one of my views with `phony_rails`. In their documentation they say to use:

```
<%= "010-12341234".phony_formatted(:normalize => :NL, :format => :international, :spaces => '-') %>
```

I'm using HAML so my markup looks like this:

```
= f.input :personal_phone.phony_formatted(:normalize => :US, :spaces => '-'), label: false
```

This returns an error `undefined method "phony_formatted" for :personal_phone:Symbol`.

I get a similar error if I try to just use a string of digits:

```
= "5551234567".phony_formatted(:normalize => :US, :spaces => '-'), label: false
```

I would like to format the number inside of the field, can anyone offer any advice on how to accomplish that? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [formtastic - how to prepopulate a string input with a value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044497/formtastic-how-to-prepopulate-a-string-input-with-a-value)

Comment: `:personal_phone.phony_formatted` here, `:personal_phone` is in fact just a symbol (which is a bit like a string that has the characters 'personal_phone' in it). You can't call a function on that symbol -it'll just give the error you gave. you need to call the function on a variable that contains an actual phone-number in it eg "5551234567" - now it so happens that that also isn't working for you... but the haml you've got wouldn't work, even if the string-version did work. So for the "555" version - can you give us the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: Also - looks like you have to have stuff in your model relating to this. Do you? can you show us (in your question, not in the comments)?