# How to format datetime field in Ruby on Rails ActiveAdmin form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, formtastic

I'm using Ruby 2.1 and Rails 4.1. I installed ActiveAdmin (1.0.0.pre2). I want to format a datetime field `expires_at` in an ActiveAdmin form. I tried this in `/app/admin/job.rb` using jQuery datepicker option:

```
f.input :expires_at, as: :datepicker, datepicker_options: { date_format: "yy-mm-dd", min_date: Time.to_s + "+7D" }
```

It perfectly works in the form of new mode `/admin/jobs/new`, but it does not work in the edit mode `/admin/jobs/xx/edit`. It always shows the value from db such as `2015-11-06 15:10:00 UTC`.

I also tried with `:value`, but it does not work either.

```
f.input :expires_at, :value => :expires_at.try(:strftime, '%Y-%m-%d'), as: :datepicker, datepicker_options: { min_date: Time.to_s + "+7D" }
```

I also have the following configuration in `/config/locales/en.yml`. However, I believe that it does not affect such form datetime fields.

```
en:
  date:
    formats:
      long: "%Y-%m-%d"
  time:
    formats:
      long: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044497/formtastic-how-to-prepopulate-a-string-input-with-a-value), the value attribute have to be wrapped with `input_html` in formtastic.

```
f.input :expires_at, :input_html => { :value => f.object.expires_at.try(:strftime, '%Y-%m-%d') }
```